# setInterval load file multiple times

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have a setInterval function in my code, that loads a json file every 1 minute and this update the data in my page.

I can see it in Chrome DevTools/Network, look like this:

```
file.json?123
```

After a minute something like this:

```
file.json?1234
```

My question is, if it is loading the file every time or just replacing the file.

In Chrome DevTools/Network at bottom appears:

10 MB Transferred | 15 MB Resource

This is increasing every time load the file again.

can this overload the page and make crash it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Need more information. We are not able to answer if memory consumption is increasing if we don't know how you load and store the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are replacing the old file by the new, your old files will be removed from your computer's memory. Make sure you are not keeping any reference to your old files in your code to be sure.

Comment: If you want to know more about this, research garbage collector

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand your files are different every time, `file.json?123` is different from `file.json?1234`. This means that these are downloaded resources, so it's fine to see a bigger value for `Transferred` and `Resource`.

You can check a similiar behaviour in an infinit scrolling page (like Facebook), where you make new request while scrolling down, so you will have new content, which means more resources and transferred data.

Comment: This increase can crash the tab in chrome?. Maybe depending on PC resources.